# Packages in Servlets

Tags: java, package

In Apache tomcat, there was a project created that included Servlets to service the incoming requests. Java class files were kept under

```
WEBINF\classes\com\example\web
```

Why do the Java files need to include "package com.example.web" statement so that their compiled classes may be kept in com\example\web folder? Tomcat container can easily locate the class files because of the Servlet mappings.
Why is this package statement necessary?

Comment: As an exercise, create 2 classes yourself. One with package and other without package. Now, inside the one with package, try to `import` and use the one without package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how the language works. You specify exactly which classes you import in order to avoid ambiguities.

Imagine the common scenario when you have two classes with the same name, but different package. Which one should be picked?

Comment: Thank You Sir,
Servlet class files are kept under web folder.
And Servlet mappings are used to facilitate the container to find these classes files.When Container has found them, why can't jvm find the classes automatically?

Comment: because the jvm comes first, and then, ontop of it, the servlet container. If the jvm could use something found by the container, it would break the layers of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

For a [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29). Apart from allowing you to have two different classes by the same names (yet making them resolvable), namespaces also help in having a logical group of classes together. I know I'd look at a util package for utility classes, a domain package for entities, a dao package for data-access classes. Imagine having them all under one hood without multiple packages. Wouldn't that be a mess ?